# Angular subscribe manejar respuesta en otro ámbito

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Necesito manejar la respuesta de un observable en un código fuera del subcribe.
Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
 this._service.findAlias(id).subscribe((resp: APIDataModel) => {
    this.aliasList = JSON.parse(resp.data);
    this.aliasSortDefault();
    ...
 }, (err: any) => {
    this.error = err.message;    
 });

 this._service.findAlias2(id, otroParametro).subscribe((resp: APIDataModel) => {
    this.aliasList = JSON.parse(resp.data);
    this.aliasSortDefault();
    ...
 }, (err: any) => {
    this.error = err.message;    
 });
```

Lo que se repite es lo que está dentro del subscribe, que desearia tratarlo por separado para no tener que repetir código.

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes crear una función común y pasarla como parámetro a ambos `subscribe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de pasar callbacks anónimos al `suscribe` puedes crear métodos comunes en tu servicio o donde toque y pasar la referencia al `subscribe`.

En tu componente o servicio.

```
handleResponse(resp: APIDataModel) {
    this.aliasList = JSON.parse(resp.data);
    this.aliasSortDefault();
    ...
}

handleError(err: any) {
    this.error = err.message;    
}
```

```
this._service.findAlias(id).subscribe(this.handleResponse, this.handleError);

this._service.findAlias2(id, otroParametro).subscribe(this.handleResponse, this.handleError);
```

Comment: amigo si te sirvió acepta la respuesta porfavor

Comment: ¿Debo importar algo? Porque al agregar el método me arroja error { or } expected

Comment: he actualizado el código habia error de sintaxis habia `=>` innecesarios

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontré otra solución:

```
let peticion: Observable<any>;
peticion = this._Service.update(this.dataObj);
peticion.subscribe(resp => {
}, (err) => {
});
```